# EF Code first 1 to 1 relationship error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship, one-to-one

I have two classes:

Main class:

```
public class CCourseDetailModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CourseDetailId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CourseOutcomes")]
    public int CourseOutcomesId { get; set; }

    public virtual CACourseOutcomesModel CourseOutcomes { get; set; }
}
```

Dependent class:

```
public class CACourseOutcomesModel
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("CourseDetail")]
    public int CourseOutcomesId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual CCourseDetailModel CourseDetail { get; set; }
}
```

I have 10 or so similar classes, with 1 to 1 relationships that work fine.  This is the only one giving me the following error:

> *CACourseOutcomesModel_CourseDetail_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'CACourseOutcomesModel_CourseDetail_Target' in
>   relationship 'CACourseOutcomesModel_CourseDetail'. Because the
>   Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound
>   of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.*

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Need a fresh set of eyes please.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a one to one relationship, one end must be principal and the another one must be dependent, so you can't have  a FK property in both sides. Remove the FK property in the principal (`CCourseDetailModel`) and in `CACourseOutcomesModel` you don't need to use `Required` attribute. Using `ForeignKey` attribute you already are telling to EF who is the dependent end.

In Fluent Api would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CACourseOutcomesModel>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.CourseDetail)
            .WithOptional(p => p.CourseOutcomes);
```

So your model should be this way:

```
public class CCourseDetailModel
{
    [Key]
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] don't need this, it's the configuration by default.
    public int CourseDetailId { get; set; }

    public virtual CACourseOutcomesModel CourseOutcomes { get; set; }
}

public class CACourseOutcomesModel
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("CourseDetail")]
    public int CourseOutcomesId { get; set; }

    public virtual CCourseDetailModel CourseDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks octavioccl! this works great, but I was wondering whether I could keep the [ForeignKey] tag in the principal model so I can work with the dependent Id.  Reason being, Say I already know the foreign key of the dependent class.  I dont want to unnecessarily call the db for the whole dependent class just so I can link it to the principal class, I just want to add the FK id of the dependent class.  Hope I was clear enough.  Any possibilities

Comment: Actually, in a 1 to 1 relationship, I think the example I gave above would rarely happen.  I usually run into that issues in 1 to many.  Thanks mate!

Comment: you're welcome, it's possible do what you ask above, but you are going to need to create two relationships instead one, so both entities wouldn't really related, and as you said, you should always create the principal first.